# I couldn' t change content tab with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

**Original Tab: Please check this URL:** http://basarhost.com/tab
**Add new tab: Please check this URL:** http://basarhost.com/tab/mynewtab/

As you can see in the web sites second one does not work properly.

Here is my javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    /* Activate H5F */

    $('ul#tabs li').click(function() {

        /* If what we clicked is the actual link, we move make the changes */
        if($(this).attr("class") == "inactiveTab") {

            /* Swap classes on the clicked item */
            $(this).addClass('activeTab').removeClass('inactiveTab');

            /* Swap classes on the other LI */
            $(this).siblings('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab').addClass('inactiveTab');

            /* Change the float of the previous element */
            $(this).prev().css("float", "left");

            /* We toggle the tabs */
            $("div.toggleTab").slideToggle("fast", function() {

                /* Once the animation is complete, focus the first field of the visible form */
                $("div.toggleTab input:visible").first().focus();

            });

        }

    });

});
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Please post relevat test case in an accessibile site like jsfiddle

Comment: It's because of `float` css property. You should set `float` property of all tabs according to your purposes, you just set everything to `float: left`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How doesn't this work properly?  Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: @John as you can see in the examples i have three divs. i want to show relational div when i click tab.

Comment: @OrkunB My apologies. I read over the post in the review queue too quickly and I did not see the very clear comments you put within the code.  Please disregard my comment, and again, welcome to SO.

Comment: I tried to explain the fact that a detailed. you're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I suggest is to change the content of functions.js to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Activate H5F */
    H5F.setup($("div#signUp form"));

    $('ul#tabs li').click(function() {

        /* If what we clicked is the actual link, we move make the changes */
        if($(this).attr("class") == "inactiveTab") {

            /* Swap classes on the clicked item */
            $(this).addClass('activeTab').removeClass('inactiveTab');

            /* Swap classes on the other LI */
            $(this).siblings('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab').addClass('inactiveTab');

            /* Change the float of the previous element */
            $(this).prev().css("float", "left");
        }

    });
    $('#signInTab').click(function() {
        $('#signUp').hide();
        $('#homeBill').hide();
        $("#signIn").slideToggle("fast", function() {
            /* Once the animation is complete, focus the first field of the visible form */
            $("#signIn input:visible").first().focus();
        });
    });
    $('#signUpTab').click(function() {
        $('#signIn').hide();
        $('#homeBill').hide();
        $("#signUp").slideToggle("fast", function() {
            /* Once the animation is complete, focus the first field of the visible form */
            $("#signUp input:visible").first().focus();
        });
    });
    $('#homeBillTab').click(function() {
        $('#signIn').hide();
        $('#signUp').hide();
        $("#homeBill").slideToggle("fast");
    });

});
```

Also you need to set your new div css to be hidden:

```
div#homeBill { display: none; }
```

**CSS FIX:**
to get rid of the annoying tab switching I suggest to modify the css of `ul#tabs li` to:

```
ul#tabs li {
    padding: 25px;
    float: left;
    width: 27.36%;
}
```

and delete `float: right;` from `ul#tabs li.inactiveTab`

Hope this helps!